# Как перенести один div в другой в каждой карточке?

Tags: javascript

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.product-cart {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-cart:hover .buttons {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.buttons {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Внутри карточек есть div "top". Внутри него div с кнопками. Как перенести этот div с кнопками после дива "price" в каждой карточке ( в каждом диве "product-cart")

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var divButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons');
  var divProducts = document.getElementsByClassName('product-cart');
  var divPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('price');

  for(var i = 0; i < divButtons.length; i++){
    divProducts[i].insertBefore(divButtons[i], divPrice[i]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Вот что я придумал. Это лучше всего лучше сделать вручную, но дело твоё

Comment: Для надёжности. лучше в цикле идти по элементам `.product-cart`, находить в них элемент `.buttons` и переносить под `.price`, т.к. за пределами `.product-cart`, могут быть другие элементы с классами `.buttons` и/или `.price` и результат будет не привлекательный.

Comment: Как вариант:  `document.querySelectorAll('.product-cart').forEach(p => { p.querySelector('.price').after(p.querySelector('.buttons')); });`

Answer (score 0):

Весьма непонятен смысл данных манипуляций... И почему нельзя сразу правильно сверстать.

Суть работы скрипта проста:

- Находим и перебираем все карточки `.product-cart`;
- Вставляем методом `insertAdjacentElement()` блок с кнопками, найденный в текущей карточке.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.product-cart')].forEach(el => {
  el.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', el.querySelector('.buttons'));
});
```

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.product-cart {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-cart:hover .buttons {
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.buttons {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>button</button>
          <button>button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="price">Price</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```